# Removing leading zeros from 1 column of a csv file

Tags: java, csv, formatting, string-formatting

I am looking for a quick way to remove the leading zeros from the first column of a CSV file so that it is nicely consumed by another program.  if possible, it would be great to also convert it from comma delimited to tab delimited, but that may have to be a separate question.

here are the header names (only need to strip leading (2) zeros from student ID):

```
"Student ID","School Name","Contact Relation","Contact First Name","Contact Last Name","Salutation"," Home Phone Number","Address Line 1","Address Line 2","City","State","Zip","Zip + 4","Work Phone","Cell Phone","Pager","Residential Status","Custodial Status"
```

and here is some sample data to see how it is formatted:

```
"004000031","Local High School","Mother","FirstName","LastName","","555-5557773","555 Old Midlothian Tpke","Lot77","Richmond","VA","23222","","","","","","Y"
```

Comment: If you're working on Linux, there are probably various command line tools you can use for this, and you can use in a pipeline to your program. Do you insist on the answer being a Java program? Are you aware of pipelining, and is it a good solution for you?

Comment: my initial reaction was Java, since that is what I am used to, but it does not have to be.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post it? What is the data type you're actually trying to manipulate (you're just showing the raw data, but what form did you turn it into, a String?)?

Comment: turns out co-worker handed it off to me just before lunch, the data could be handled differently as it was exported, I was able to strip off the leading zeros within thier XML export script as well as switch it to tab delimited.

not sure how to close the question now.

the XML code used is: 

      <field id="stdIDLocal"  header-source="field"  header-value="Student ID"  find="00" replaceFirst="" />
 
To convert your output from CSV to Tab-Delimited file use the following XML Statement in your <export> tag:
 
    <export table-id="tblStudent" header-row="true" value-delimiter="&#09;" >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified the XML code that was generating the CSV file.  just needed to add/modify 2 lines

```
 <field id="stdIDLocal" header-source="field" header-value="Student ID"     find="00" replaceFirst="" />
```

To convert your output from CSV to Tab-Delimited file use the following XML Statement in your  tag:

```
<export table-id="tblStudent" header-row="true" value-delimiter="&#09;" >
```

Answer (score 0):

This line should do that:

```
String[] tokens = String.join("\t", csv.replaceFirst("^\"0*", "\"").split(","));
```

Comment: This doesn't compile, I think you forgot to close the `join` before calling `split`. Also, what if the student ID has more than 2 leading zeros? Then more than two characters will be removed. I think regex is a little overboard if every ID *definitely* contains two leading 0s.

Comment: @Oli: remove the `[]` and it works; `join` and `split` are just fine. Some explanation would be nice. May be the solution is not obvious to everyone.

Answer (score -1):

This perl should do it for you.

First expression deletes the first two zeros of each line.
Second one changes `,`, to tab.

`perl -pne 's/^00//;s/,/\t/g' your_file.txt`

Comment: This is a Java question.